# Centre pole construction for 20 metre half wave dipole

Tags: antenna-construction, hf, propagation

I am about to embark on the construction of an inverted V half wave dipole. It will possibly be multi-band but, for the moment, I want to build it for 20M. Because of the shape of my property, I would like the centre pole to be as high as possible to give me the correct angle for the inverted V. I thought that I might be able to make this from sections of aluminium tubing. I even sourced a company that would supply these but I have carelessly lost the page and can't seem to get it again.

So, basically, can anybody tell me the best material to use for the centre pole and possibly how I might source it. I would also be grateful for any suggestion as to the type of wire to use for the actual antenna.

Thanks

Comment: The search terms for here and elsewhere is "mast". This is a very well-trod subject, and there are as many kinds of masts as you have room for in your yard, from many different materials. What research have you done yourself? What features do you need? Also, it's best to stick to a single question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

We've all been there, looking at the various ways to hold up our antennas and it usually boils down to some considerations.

- Does it need to be self-supporting or guyed?
- Does it need to be as inexpensive as possible?
- Will you have some help in putting it up?

Some of the early ARRL antenna books had plans to build a self-supporting wooden lattice tower but that seems to have fallen out of favor in recent years.

[image]

Most of us would suggest trying to find a commercial tower for sale in good used condition via Craigslist or other local shopping sites.

Some folks have opted for push-up masts but they require substantial guy wires at various levels as they go higher.  Metal wires can interact with RF, they obstruct your lowering of the antenna for maintenance and they're rather unsightful (if you have a spouse or finicky neighbors).

Here is one solution for a DIY wooden support:

[Home Made Support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBX0DwcaB6w)

(EDIT) Here's another one that has some merit:

[One-Man Mast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSbuHE6-TLE)

Again, the best way to go here would be to find a good, used tower at a reasonable price. If you can't manage that, then some less desirable compromises might be your only way to go.